# SiriKit: call contact with multiple phone numbers

Tags: objective-c, swift, siri, sirikit

Im make Siri Integration. I have a problem because I don't know how to resolve contacts for contact with two or more numbers.

I need something like this:

[image]

Instead of this Siri offers me to choose two contacts with the same name.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems not possible with current iOS10 API. I had similar problem and made a workaround - if request is resolved to a single person with multiple phone numbers, then I return phone numbers as a persons (INPerson) instead of returning person itself. However Siri will still ask for a "name", not a "phone number".